# elasticsearch returning unique values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field named 'category'.

I can return the list of possible categories by just doing:

```
$searchParams['body']['aggs']['category']['terms']['field'] = 'category';
```

But I want to search inside that field and return only categories matching my query.

Example list:

1. Pizza
2. Apple pie
3. Orange pie
4. Cupcake
5. Burger

I want to search for "pie" and have the following result:

1. Apple pie
2. Orange pie

There are more than 200 categories. I want to do this the elasticsearch way, not using MySQL as the search.

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: I can't see any ElasticSearch index structure nor what queries you have tried. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregations operate in the ["scope" of the query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scoping_aggregations.html).  So if you execute a search query for `"pie"`, the aggregation will only see (and aggregate) "pie" documents.

```
$query = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'search_type' => 'count',  // <-- Note search_type = count, to ignore search hits
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'category' => 'pie'
            ]
        ],
        'aggs' => [
            'category' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'category'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

$results = $client->search($query);
```

Comment: That's correct. But I will get all the products with category pie. I just need to find distinct category names based on my query, in this case pie. I would get like 50 apple pies and 200 orange pies. I need just need apple pie and orange pie in a list, not the items with that category.

Comment: Oooh, I see.  in that case you can use the `count` search type, which only returns the aggregation results (and no search results).  I'll edit my answer to demonstrate